# A mounted device is busy because bash is using the volume

Tags: mount, lsof

If I try to umount a mounted disk. It says I can't because it is used by another process, which is strange because I have nothing accessing it that I can find. So I tried using lsof to find what is using it. And the result is as below

[image]

I can't because of bash. Well that's the most generic info ever. How can I find what specifically is using it?

Comment: Yes you are currently in that directory , first get out of that directory and then umount. when you get out of that directory and then run `lsof` again there will be no bash process using that and you will be able to umount it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are current "in" the mounted drive. It says that in your screenshot here:

```
[root@localhost vldsk_damo]
```

If you issue `pwd` (at a guess) it will say:

```
/mnt/vldsk_damo
```

Best fix, type `cd` (to send you to your `$HOME`) or `cd /`, then try `umount ...`